# Panda to_csv() : TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found

Tags: python, pandas, unicode, buffer, typeerror

I'm trying to merge multiple CSV files into a single big CSV for my dataset. What I'm looking for is to fetch few column data from multiple CVS files and make a dataset out of it. I don't want all the columns in my final datasets but few selected ones. I have used `names` attribute in panda while reading CSV and it's returning fine but I'm not able to create a new CSV out of the fetched ones. What am I doing wrong in here? I have added the stack trace at the bottom.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

path = "C:\Users\lenovo\Downloads\Compressed\LoanStats3a.csv_2\csv"
class MergeCsvFiles:
def MergeCsv(self):
    allFiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "LoanStats3a.csv"))
    print 'allFiles',allFiles

    for file_ in allFiles:
        print 'file_ ######### ',file_

        # merge_df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(file_)
        # print merge_df
        fileToSave = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "merge.csv"))
        print 'filrToSave #### ', fileToSave
        np_array_list = []

        df = pd.read_csv(file_, skipinitialspace=True,low_memory=False,header=0,index_col=None)
        np_array_list.append(df.as_matrix())
        comb_np_array = np.vstack(np_array_list)
        big_frame = pd.DataFrame(comb_np_array)
        # big_frame.columns = fields
        print 'big_frame#### ', big_frame
        big_frame.to_csv(fileToSave)

        # See the keys
        print 'df.keys########',df.keys()
        print 'df @@@@@', df
        frame = pd.DataFrame()
        list_ = []

        list_.append(df)
        frame = pd.concat(list_)
        # print 'frame#### ',frame

        frame.to_csv(fileToSave)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    s =  MergeCsvFiles()
    s.MergeCsv()
```

StackTrace :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/lenovo/Downloads/Video/Machine Learning/MLPredictiveAnalysis/MergeCsv.py", line 59, in <module>
    s.MergeCsv()
  File "C:/Users/lenovo/Downloads/Video/Machine Learning/MLPredictiveAnalysis/MergeCsv.py", line 39, in MergeCsv
    big_frame.to_csv(fileToSave)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1344, in to_csv
    formatter.save()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\formats\format.py", line 1526, in save
    compression=self.compression)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 426, in _get_handle
    f = open(path, mode)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found
```

Comment: `glob.glob` returns a list. You need to pass a string of the path name to `big_frame.csv`. Why do you even need glob? `big_frame.csv(os.path.join(path, "merge.csv"))` should work

Comment: Thanks.It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glob.glob` returns a list. You need to pass a string of the path name to big_frame.csv. Why do you even need glob? `big_frame.csv(os.path.join(path, "merge.csv"))` should work.

You are also writing this file over with `frame.to_csv(fileToSave)` at the bottom of your loop. And every iteration is writing the file over as well so only the last iteration will save any file.